# How do I properly link changing data from an AsyncTask to a TextView in my Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Let's say I have an `Activity` which displays a `View` containing a `TextView`.
My `Activity` also have an `AsyncTask` (running continuously) which retrieve data (a changing value) from a web server every second or so.
What I want is to monitor the data from the web server by displaying it in the `TextView`.

So far I always ask my `AsyncTask` to do the `setText` in the `onProgressUpdate`, so my `TextView`'s display is refreshed every time I get new data... is there a better way ?

Thanks for reading me.

PS : In the end, I'll have at least two Activities, both having an AsyncTask of the previously described variety.

Comment: " ... is there a better way ? " What is wrong with this way?

Comment: Is having UI's operations separated from data processing not a better practise ? Like trying to do modular programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to separate the data and display a bit more, you could follow a listener pattern:

Make your Activity implement a new interface - something like:

```
public interface boolean OnTextUpdatedListener {
  onTextUpdated(int id, String newText);
}
```

and the implementation (in your Activity):

```
@Override
public boolean onTextUpdated(int id, String newText) {
  TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(id);
  if(tv == null) {
    return false;
  }
  tv.setText(newText);
  return true;
}
```

And a AsyncTask that looks something like this:

```
 public class TextUpdater extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
        OnTextUpdatedListener mListener;
        int mId;
        volatile boolean mRunning;

            public TextUpdater(OnTextUpdatedListener listener, int id) {
        super();
        mListener = listener;
        mId = id;
    }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            mRunning = mListener.onTextUpdated(mId, values[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            mRunning = true;
            while(mRunning) {
                //retrieve text from network
                this.publishProgress(downloadedText);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            mListener = null;
        }
    }
```

Your Activity keeps control of the UI, the AsyncTask downloads and notifies when something is updated.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of practise I was searching for. Thanks a lot FunkTheMonk.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the fetched data changed from the preciously fetched, the text of the `TextView` should change as well (and so you have to call the `setText` method). You could store the last data and test the new data against the last one `onProgressUpdate`, so that you will only change the `TextView`'s text when necessary. The test can be done with any string matching algorithm, for example.

Comment: Thanks Alesqui. My question was not clear. You are exactly describing what I'm doing : calling the setText from the onProgressUpdate. What I want to know is : is there a way to do it in a more OOP way than having a class fetching the data and displaying the data.

Comment: Well, you could create a class to hold the TextView and the other UI components and a method to notify to this class that the TextView's text changed. The fetcher class would only notify the UI class about the data change, but it would be the UI class to deal with the info. You could even use Singleton, as you wished only one UI Class... I don't know if that's what you wanted, but it would work and be a pretty code :)